# How do I incorporate the AutoAnchors jquery plugin into my web page?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to the HTML5 world and I could use some help with how to use this javascript file.

> jquery.autoanchors-0.3

It is found here. http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/autoanchors.php

How do I do use this? How can I include this in the html file in the  and the js file how will it automatically add the anchors/links to the html file?

```
 <script src="js/jquery.autoanchors-0.3.js"></script>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks
damon

Comment: It's a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin so you'll need that first.

Comment: You need to read up on the basics. Search around for jQuery/javascript html tutorials

Answer (score 0):

as sachleen points out you'll need jQuery first.

1. Download jQuery (http://jquery.com/download/)
2. Include both jQuery and autoanchors into the head of your html file
3. Follow the instructions on the autoanchors page (http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/autoanchors.php#usage)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the head section of your webpage, which will add jQuery to your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" /></script>
```

Download the Autoanchors.js file and add it to your site (put it in a folder named js):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autoanchors-0.3.js"></script>
```

Then follow the instructions on that site under "usage" which would look like this (this goes in the head, right under the line above):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.demo").autoAnchors();
});
</script>
```